# What is a Mlechha and what are their religious rights?

Tags: moksha, varna, arya

I am a Muslim born who left Islam 2 years ago, although I am still a theist. I am currently researching about other religions and as of now, I like Hinduism better than any religion I have studied.

But there is one thing which is confusing me. What exactly is the concept of Arya and Mlechha? Is it synonymous to Astika (believer of Vedas) and Nastika (disbeliever of Vedas) or is it something based on lineage or is it a mixture of both lineage and faith?

I am a Sayyid (descendant of Muhammad, therefore have Arabic lineage) but my ancestors had settled in India centuries ago, so I have many Indian converted ancestors too.

Would I be classified as a Mlechha? If yes then are they any religious practices which I can't do? Also am I eligible to get moksha or should I consider this birth as a result of my past karma and do something to be born an Arya in next birth?